# Show that $\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)$ iff $\overline\lambda\in\sigma_r(T')$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a complex Banach space, $T\in\mathfrak L(X)$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.

> Are we able to show $\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)$ (the point spectrum of $T$) if and only if $\overline\lambda\in\sigma_r(T')$ (the residual spectrum of $T':X'\to X'$)?

I'm only able to (partially) prove this claim under the assumption that $X$ is a Hilbert space and $T'$ is replaced by the Hilbert space adjoint $T^\ast:X\to X$:

In that situation, if $S\in\mathfrak L(X)$, then $$\mathcal N(S)={\mathcal R(S^\ast)}^\perp\tag1$$ from which we infer that $S$ is injective if and only if $\mathcal R(S^\ast)$ is dense. Substituting $S=\lambda-T$ and noting that $(\lambda-T)^\ast=\overline\lambda-T^\ast$, it is only left to show that if $\lambda-T$ is not injective (hence $\mathcal R(\overline\lambda-T^\ast)$ is not dense), then $\overline\lambda-T^\ast$ is injective.

> How can we show this? And are we able to prove the desired equivalence in the general Banach space case well?

Answer (score 1):

No.  If $X_1=X_2$, and $T$ is given by $T(x)=\lambda x$, with $\lambda\in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$, then
$$
  T'(\phi)=\lambda \phi, \quad\forall \phi\in  X_2',
  $$
so the spectra of both operators coincide with their point spectra and
$$
  \sigma (T) = \sigma (T')=\{\lambda \} \neq  \{\bar \lambda \}.
  $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the Hilbert space case? How can we finish the proof?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by the spectrum of a linear transformation between *different* spaces?

Comment: Sorry, I've started with $(1)$, which clearly holds for operators between different Hilbert spaces, but the actual question doesn't make sense, unless these spaces are equal. Fixed that.

Comment: It is better now, although you have forgotten a few $X_i$ here and there.  Regarding your question, have you tried $T =$ identity map?

Comment: Well, it is clear to me that whenever $T$ is normal (which the identity clearly is), then $\lambda\in\sigma_p(A)$ iff $\overline\lambda\in\sigma_p(A^\ast)$.

Comment: Your question asks about the *residual* spectrum, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. It seems like the result I just stated contradicts what I'm trying to show, right? So, is the result I'm asking for in the question wrong (even in the Hilbert space case)?

Comment: Still interested in this one.